# How can i call the same ViewController from different TabBar items?

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem

I've developed a ViewController that shows different data according to the input parameter. I would like to use a `tabBar` interface and call the same ViewController from different tabs by passing them to different parameters.
Can I do this? I get errors if I specify the ViewController's NIB in `tabBar` item.

Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the solution here: http://www.iphonelife.co.uk/creating-a-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two different instances of your ViewController:

```
MyViewController *vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

UITabBarController *tabs = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabs setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil] animated:NO];
```